# How do I make a realistic shiny gloss lips texture?

Tags: texturing

How do I make this texture of lips? I checked out how to make leather but they don't address the wrinkles. I know I could just take this image and align it to my character's lips but that won't work if the light source is to the side.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can paint a bump map to affect the normal of the material here, drawing/painting the wrinkles in varying values of white on a black map. Once you have the map, you can use it to determine the bump as I mention but also use it as a factor to the amount of gloss, so that the glossy only shows on the highest parts.